# MatFormField is not Focused when click on SVG

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I would like to create matFormField with clear button (which delete input's value when clicked) And I cannot use matIcon . So I use SVG instead . Clear button is shown when matFormField is focused, if not it'll be hidden. However when I click on clear button , matFormField is not focused and clear button is hidden so the button is not work.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <div class="displayFlex" > 
    <input type="text" matInput [placeholder]="controlName">
    <svg class="clear" (click)="clearInput('control')" fill="#000000" height="17" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: If you would prefer to use `click` instead of `mousedown`, you could wrap the code of `clearInput` in a `setTimeout` callback to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to the input field, and focus it upon click. You can do it both via html, or via the component, by first obtaining the element with  @ViewChild().

The solution via HTML is as follows :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <div class="displayFlex" > 
    <input type="text" matInput [placeholder]="controlName" #myInput>
    <svg class="clear" (click)="clearInput('control'); myInput.focus()" fill="#000000" height="17" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Notice the `#myInput` template reference variable (this could have a name of your choise) annotated to the input field, and the `myInput.focus()` call referenced via the click handler associated with the SVG element.

Alternatively, you can perform the focus handling within the component. To do so, reference your input element, as below.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <div class="displayFlex" > 
    <input type="text" matInput [placeholder]="controlName" #someName>
    <svg class="clear" (click)="clearInput('control')" fill="#000000" height="17" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your component class, reference the input element via the @ViewChild decorator, and call the native focus method call as below.

```
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('someName') private inputField:ElementRef;

    ... Your logic here

    clearInput() {
       ... Your current logic
       // Focus on the element
       this.inputField.nativeElement.focus();
       // You can also clear the value of the input element via the inputField reference also
       this.inputField.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
}
```

Read more about template reference variables [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).

Read more about ViewChild decorators [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

Comment: I just found the solution . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution , just us (mousedown) instead of (click) . When mousedown is emitted the SVG is still shown .